# Connect angular module and service dependencies using jest testing framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jestjs

I'm tryin to configure jest testing framework for [my simple application](https://github.com/rantiev/webpack2-angular-config-sample)

And getting issues like that:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module dib due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angulartics due to:
```

And so on.

Can't understand how to connect all main module dependencies and service being tested dependencies with jest at one place.

Should i list all submodules in package.json, or in each test file?